# Why was an American who overstayed in Singapore not caned?

Tags: singapore

The US citizen Kamari Kenyada Charlton overstayed his visa while in Singapore. The [law](https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Act/IA1959#pr6-) is that this shall "be punished with caning with not less than 3 strokes".

However, according to [this story](https://www.asiaone.com/print/News/AsiaOne%2BNews/Crime/Story/A1Story20110221-264712.html), he was jailed 18 months for his telephone scam and seems to not have received any punishment for overstaying. Why?

More background:

- [*WSJ*, "U.S. Man Faces Caning in Singapore", Oct 20 2010](https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424052702304011604575564012145605090)
- [*WaPo*, "U.S. citizen faces possible caning in Singapore", Oct 22 2010](http://voices.washingtonpost.com/checkpoint-washington/2010/10/us_citizen_faces_possible_cani.html)"
- [Gopalan Nair, "Singapore. One law for some and another for others. The case of American Kamari Kenyada Charlton", Feb 21, 2011](http://singaporedissident.blogspot.com/2011/02/singapore-one-law-for-some-and-another.html)

---

The caning punishment is regularly enforced for overstayers from poor Asian countries (and also any who aid such overstayers):

- [*Channel News Asia*, "Foreign inmate diagnosed with COVID-19 had arrived on Jan 10, sentenced to jail and caning on Jun 12 for overstaying", 20 Jun 2020](https://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/singapore/covid-19-changi-prison-inmate-overstaying-jail-12854542) (Sri Lankan)
- [*Yahoo News*, "Vietnamese man who overstayed in Singapore for over 10 years gets jail, caning", 2 April 2019](https://sg.news.yahoo.com/vietnamese-man-overstayed-singapore-10-years-gets-jail-caning-113447453.html)
- [*The Straits Times*, Indonesian gets two years' jail for attempt to sneak overstayer out of Singapore, Jul 8 2016](https://www.straitstimes.com/singapore/courts-crime/indonesian-gets-two-years-jail-for-attempt-to-sneak-overstayer-out-of)
- [*Today*, Man convicted for helping Bangladeshi overstayer: ICA, 28 March 2017](https://www.todayonline.com/singapore/bangladeshi-overstayer-arrested-after-attempting-leave-singapore-ica)

Answer (score 3):

### [Plea bargain](https://www.straitstimes.com/opinion/plea-bargaining-singapore-style)

Probably.

Like all common law jurisdictions, Singapore practices plea bargaining. While not formalised as it is in the USA, a prosecutor can agree to drop certain charges and/or not pursue certain sentences in return for a guilty plea to others.

As it says in your link, the defendant “pleaded guilty to five charges last week.
17 other charges, including one for overstaying in Singapore, were taken into consideration.”

So, he was *not* convicted of overstaying his visa.